# Most efficient way to select users for each row in an html table

Tags: php, html, sql, postgresql

I'll try to explain it in an easy way:

-I have a table "elections", each election has an id and some other fields (eg. number votes, start date, etc.).
-I have a table "candidates", each candidate has an "candidate for election" field which is an external reference to the id field of elections table. In short: you can candidate for a specific election editing this field.

Now, I want to make a table and for each row have a thing like that:

```
election id | election description | candidates (<select> <option> construct
```

Each row has a `<select> <option>` scroll menu, and it contains candidates for the specific election.

Now, the first idea I have is to make a select query for each row:

```
select id from candidates where election=row_id
```

but it seems low efficient to me: for each row I create I have to make a query.

Is there a better way?

Example:

elections:

```
id|end date | role
2 | 01/01/2012 | major
3 | 01/02/2012 | secretary
```

users:

```
id| name |election 
1 |donald | 2
2 |goofy | 2
3 |mickey | 3
```

now a simple html row:

```
01/01/2012 | major | **select/option choice with goofy and donald**

01/02/2012 | secretary| **select/option choice with just mickey**
```

Comment: . . Your question would be more answerable if you provided sample data and the results you want.  Sentences such as "you can candidate for a specific election editing this field" simply make no sense (at least to me).

Comment: i inserted an example

Comment: If you're learning this stuff, look into using a PHP framework and an Object Relational Mapper (ORM) such as Symfony/Doctrine or Laravel/Eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mostly there.  The only thing I would do is to select everything including your row identifier in a single query.

```
select id from candidates where election=row_id
```

would be replaced with

```
select election, id from candidates where election in (row_id_1, row_id_2, etc);
```

Now you could further do this like:

```
SELECT election, array_agg(id) from candidates 
 where election in (row_id_1, row_id_2, etc)
ORDER BY election
GROUP BY election;
```

And then for each election you'd get an array of candidates like: `{1, 3, 55}`

If you strip off the brackets on the outside you can use csv parsing routines to pull out the members of the array.